# Combine separate RRD files to a single graph

Tags: java, rrdtool, rrd, rrd4j

Using **rrd4j**, how can I combine several `.rrd` files either into a single `.rrd` or (ideally) to a single graph?

More details:

I have several copies of essentially the same `.rrd`. Each file records several sensor data readings, all with the name `sensor-1`, `sensor-2` across files. So `data1.rrd`, `data2.rrd` will all contain data sources of `sensor-1` etc.

The DS definition is as follows.

```
DS:sensor-1:GAUGE:35:U:U DS:sensor-2:GAUGE:35:U:U DS:sensor-3:GAUGE:35:U:U
```

I can generate a graph for each individually by adding a data source to a graph like this;

```
val graph = new RrdGraphDef()
graph.datasource("sensor-1", data1.rrd", "sensor-1", AVERAGE)
graph.datasource("sensor-2", data1.rrd", "sensor-1", AVERAGE)
graph.line("sensor-1", green)
graph.line("sensor-2", red)
```

but if I do the same but for `data2.rrd` (adding another datasource to the same `graph` instance), it seems to loose the preceding data and graphs just one of the file's data.

I suspect that each DS having the same name across files may be a problem.

*Suggestions on how to achieve the same with regular RRD tool might also be helpful as I might be able to translate to rrd4j*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement:

`graph.datasource("varname", "filename.rrd", "dsname", AVERAGE)`

defines a new variable to use called `varname`, which corresponds to the DS `dsname` in the file `filename.rrd`, consolodated using the `AVERAGE` Consolodation Function.

Clearly, you cannot have two variables in the same graph with the same name; however, there is nothing to prevent you from pulling data from multiple different RRD files, and nothing to prevent you from using a different varname to the DS name.

However, you should only use alphanumerics in the variable name -- in particular, avoid '-', even though it is supposed to work.  Underscores are OK.

So, this is perfectly valid:

`graph.datasource("sensora", "sitea.rrd", "sensor", AVERAGE)
graph.datasource("sensorb", "siteb.rrd", "sensor", AVERAGE)`

and will define two variables, `sensora` and `sensorb` corresponding to the same named DS in two different RRD files.

Do not use `sensor-1` as a varname, as it contains a '-' symbol.

Not having seen the RRD4j code that is failing I can't say for certain, but I would suspect it is either because you are not renaming the varname, making both variables share the same name and overwrite one another, or because of the '-' in the varname.